# inserting datatables into sql server that are linked

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

i have two datatables that i am inserting into sql server 2008 using `SqlBulkCopy`

here they are:

```
      QuickLabDump = new DataTable();
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Specimen ID", typeof(string));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Client Key", typeof(int));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Outcome", typeof(string));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Medications", typeof(string));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Date Collected", typeof(DateTime));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Time Collected", typeof(TimeSpan));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Date Entered", typeof(DateTime));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Time Entered", typeof(TimeSpan));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Date Completed", typeof(DateTime));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Time Completed", typeof(TimeSpan));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Test Date", typeof(DateTime));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Test Time", typeof(TimeSpan));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Practice Name", typeof(string));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Practice Code", typeof(string));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Client ID", typeof(string));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Requesting Physician", typeof(string));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Other Medications", typeof(string));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Order Comments", typeof(string));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Reference Number", typeof(string));
            QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Order Count", typeof(int));    

            TestResults = new DataTable();
            TestResults.Columns.Add("TestName", typeof(String));
            TestResults.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(Decimal));
            TestResults.Columns.Add("NonNumericResult", typeof(String));
            TestResults.Columns.Add("QuickLabDumpid", typeof(int));
```

on the database they are:

```
[Specimen ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Client Key] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Outcome] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Medications] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Date Collected] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Time Collected] [time](0) NOT NULL,
    [Date Entered] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Time Entered] [time](0) NOT NULL,
    [Date Completed] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Time Completed] [time](0) NOT NULL,
    [Test Date] [date] NULL,
    [Test Time] [time](0) NULL,
    [Practice Name] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Practice Code] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Client ID] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Requesting Physician] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Other Medications] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Order Comments] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Reference Number] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Order Count] [int] NOT NULL,
    [QuickLabDumpID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

and

```
[TestName] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Result] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    [NonNumericResult] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [QuickLabDumpID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TestResultsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

`[QuickLabDumpID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL` this one is autoincrement. each time a row is inserted it increments. it is also a foreign key for the same column on the other table.

**question** i have no problem inserting records into either table; however, i need  to preserve the referential integrity so that the `QuickLabDumpID` on the first table matches the `QuickLabDumpID` on the other table.

i do NOT want to use `@@identity` because i am inserting 100million rows and this will take days!! i have tried it.

Comment: everyone please let me know if you do not understand my question :) i will rephrase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your best option is to `SET IDENTITY_INSERT QuickLabDump ON` before the bulk copy and then turn it off afterwards.

You will then need to generate ids for each of the rows to be inserted unless they are already present in the incoming data set.

Comment: would i have to disable the constraints?

Comment: You shouldn't have to if both incoming data sets contain the same values. i.e. QuickLabDump.QuickLabDumpId = 5 and TestResults.QuickLabDumpId = 5 in the incoming data. If this is the case, then you will insert the QuickLabDump data first which will have the correct PK, then the TestResults which will have the correct FK.

Comment: there is a 1:infinity relationship between QuickLabDump.QuickLabDumpId and TestResults.QuickLabDumpId

Comment: That should be just fine in this scenario. It might make the insert slightly faster if you remove the FK from TestResults prior to inserting then add it back in at the end (this is our standard practice when performing large data upgrades).